# Meaning of うっとひる

Tags: meaning

Maruo is being asked to get rid of a wild dog by his classmates:

> 1. 「退治してくんなきゃ、学級委員の資格ないぞブー」
> 2. はまじと関口と三人組のブー太郎が大まじめな顔で言うと、**丸尾君がうっとひるんだ**。
> 3. 「そうだそうだ、丸尾やれ～～～～」
> 4. 「丸尾君、おねがいーーーー」
> 5. クラス中から声があがった。
>
> "Unless you get rid of it you're not qualified to be class representative"
> When the trio of Hamaji, Sekiguchi and Buutarou say this with serious faces Maruo ???
> "That's right. That's right. Maruo ???"
> "Pleeeease Maruo."
> Voices were raised throughout the class.

I have two problems with this scene:

1. For the part in bold (丸尾君がうっとひるんだ), I'm not at all sure what this means.　うっとひる does not appear to be a word at all. The only sensible translation of ひる in Weblio is 放る, meaning "to expel". So I'm guessing that うっとひる is something like "let out a gulp" / "expel his breath". Something like that. Am I close? This meaning of ひる doesn't even appear in my good paper dictionary. Is this a common word/phrase?
2. Because I'm not sure of the above I'm not even sure who speaks in line 3 (そうだそうだ、丸尾やれ～～～～). I see two possibilities:

   a) Either it is Maruo's classmates telling him to do it (i.e. get rid of the dog) with やれ as the imperative of やる.
   b) It is Maruo speaking and やれ～～ is a truncated, stammering やれられる, with Maruo saying that he **can** get rid of the dog. Maruo seems to stammer a lot in this story, so I wondered if that's what the wiggly line represented.

Comment: 「うっ」と、ひるんだ、ですから、「ひるむ」って動詞を調べてみたら？

Comment: @Chocolate Argh. Embarrassing. I'm an idiot. I kept reading that as ひる+ん+だ and was wondering why it was in present tense. Now it makes sense. Although I'm still not certain about who speaks in line 3.

Comment: What would he have meant by やれられる? The potential form of やる is やれる.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It's parsed as 「うっ」と、ひるんだ。

ひるんだ is the past tense form of the verb ひるむ.

2. It's (a).

やれ is the imperative form of やる.

「クラス中から声があがった。」とありますが、その上の２行は、その「声」で、
クラスの男子が、「そうだそうだ、丸尾やれ～～～～」と言って、
クラスの女子が、「丸尾君、おねがいーーーー」と言ったんです。

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain what うっ is please? Is it a gasp, a gulping sound...?

Comment: はい、a gasp, a gulping sound だと思います。「Ugh」みたいなのかな？

Comment: "Ugh" could work, but I would say that is normally used for a sound of disgust/revulsion

Comment: ああ、そうなんですね。ここでは丸尾君は、ビビッて（＝怖がって・[怖気]{おじけ}づいて？）、困っている感じですね。

Comment: For a quick sound of surprise, which also overlaps nicely with the source text, one might say _"oop!"_